# Django-native/ORM based approach to self join

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

Trying to set up a Django-native query that grabs all rows/relationships when it shows up on the other side of many-to-many relationship.

I can explain with an example:

```
# Django models

class Ingredient:
    id = ...
    name = ...
    ...

class Dish:
    id = ...
    name = ...
    ...

class IngredientToDish
    # this is a many to many relationship
    ingredient_id = models.ForeignKey("Ingredient", ...)
    dish_id = models.ForeignKey("Dish", ...)
    ...
```

I'd like a Django-native way of: "For each dish that uses tomato, find all the ingredients that it uses".
Looking for a list of rows that looks like:

```
(cheese_id, pizza_id)
(sausage_id, pizza_id)
(tomato_id, pizza_id)
(cucumber_id, salad_id)
(tomato_id, salad_id)
```

I'd like to keep it in one DB query, for optimization. In SQL this would be a simple JOIN with itself (`IngredientToDish` table), but couldn't find what the conventional approach with Django would be... Likely uses some form of `select_related` but haven't been able to make it work; I think part of the reason is that I haven't been able to succinctly express the problem in words to come across the right documentation during research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [**`.filter(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) with:

```
Ingredient.objects.filter(
    ingredienttodish__dish_id__ingredienttodish__ingredient_id__name='Tomato'
)
```

You can also add the primary key of the dish for which this holds with:

```
from django.db.models import F

Ingredient.objects.filter(
    ingredienttodish__dish_id__ingredienttodish__ingredient_id__name='Tomato'
).annotate(
    dish_id=F('ingredienttodish__dish_id')
)
```

The `Ingredient` objects that arise from this `QuerySet` will have an extra attribute `dish_id` that contains the primary key of the `Dish` for which these were used.

---

> **Note**: Normally one does not add a suffix `…_id` to a `ForeignKey` field, since Django
> will automatically add a "twin" field with an `…_id` suffix. Therefore it should
> be `dish`, instead of <s>`dish_id`</s>.